# CKAN search data

Tags: postgresql, solr, ckan

Well, I imported data in CKAN, exactly a csv file by URL. When this csv is previewed we can find a toolbar enable on the left.

[image: data preview and toolbar]

With this toolbar we can do searches and add filters but i have a problem. When i do a search where the querie is really done? In Solr, I can view how the querie its done when i select a group, an organization, a dataset and a resource.

[image: Solr log]

If i do a search in the previous toolbar i cant see that search in Solr. I tried with the Postgres log and nothing. So I think that the search is not done in solr or postgres.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed CKAN's DataStore and DataPusher then the CSV will be loaded into postgres and the query will be done in postgres. This is the ideal situation.

CKAN's fallback is to send the request off to the DataProxy, a little service running on AppEngine, that downloads the CSV file, processes the query and returns the result. It gets overloaded sometimes, and only copes with simpler CSVs, but it is better than nothing. I think this is what you're seeing, and why you're not seeing the search in the logs. There's more about the DataProxy here:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/data-viewer.html#data-explorer

Comment: Instead of the DataPusher you can also use [ckanext-xloader](https://github.com/davidread/ckanext-xloader)